# jQuery.contents() Gives a strange result

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

I'm having a very strange occurrence when using an `IFrame` and [`jQuery.Contents`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

We have a number of reports that are built in seperate pages, and a display page that uses jQuery Tabs to display a number of these pages at once.

These reports are of varying sizes based on the data and the inputs by the user, since they can vary we needed to dynamically set the height of the IFrame to be the height of the contents. To get the height of the contents I am using this following code :

```
    var iframeHeight = $(this).contents().height();
    iframeHeight += 50;
    console.log(iframeHeight);
```

This code works fine on first load, but after the IFrame Postsback/Refreshes the `iframeHeight` that is logged is always `83px` more than the previous height, regardless of the actual contents of the child page.

```
i.e. First report is 500px high, 
     Second report should be 300px high 
     but $(this).contents().height(); returns 583px.
```

Here is an example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nunners/rq5S5/) to demonstrate the problem. If you open the console and then click the `JSFiddle` Icon in the top left of the IFrame, you will notice that the logged height will be `83px` more than the previous.

1. Is there anything that could explain this issue?
2. Am I miss-understanding how the `jQuery.Contents` function works?
3. If this will not work this way is there a better way to get the content height? (I've tried the height of the body + the height of the `form` object but this didn't work in IE).

*Tested this in IE10 + Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m*

Comment: This [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rq5S5/4/) works fine.. the only difference to your example, is that the contents do not try to adjust to the height (*as the fiddle.jshell.net does.. and also has scripts that resize elements etc..*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli - Thanks for the fiddle, you lead me to the issue of why it continued to grow (it was because for the `+=50`). However your solution doesn't take into account that the content can change height after postback. Here is an updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/rq5S5/4/) with the content change, if you click the link "THIS LINKS TO SMALLER CONTENT" the logged height value is still the same, even though the contents is less.

Comment: just added answer.. i think the safest is to target  the `contentDocument.documentElement` of the `iframe` and also use `outerHeight(true)` to account for margins/paddings that might exist..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help I managed to finally find a solution, suggested examples worked on JSFiddle's but would not work when applied to my issue using ASP.NET controls generated on PostBack.

To handle this, on each of my Child pages I have wrapped the entire content inside a `<div></div>` and retrieved the height of this element.

Example :

```
<div id="ReportContent">
    <!-- HTML Content -->
</div>
```

And the jQuery Code :

```
var iframeHeight = $(this).contents().find('#ReportContent').outerHeight(true);
```

This now works correctly for my problem in both **IE10** and **Google Chrome Version 31.0.1650.57 m**

Answer (score 1):

Here is an implementation that seems to work (*for expanding/shrinking contents..*)

assuming that iframe's src is from the same domain and that there are not scripts that resize the iframe's contents once loaded

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#frameID').on('load', function () {
        $('#ReportBuild').hide()
        $(this).show();

        var iframeHeight = $(this.contentDocument.documentElement).outerHeight(true);
        $(this).css({ height: iframeHeight + 'px' });

        this.contentWindow.onbeforeunload = function () {
            $('.tabFrame').hide();
            $('#ReportBuild').show();
        }
    });
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/rq5S5/8/

Comment: Thanks for this, your fiddle works exactly how you'd expect, however on my actual site this doesn't work. What I'm using for the example is a simple ASP.NET webpage and I'm binding a GridView on postback. The height of the Frame is not getting smaller on each postback :(. This is insanely confusing...

Comment: Thanks for the help, you led me down the right path on solving this issue, The solution was to wrap all of the contents in the child page with a `<div></div>` and find the height of the div : `var iframeHeight = $(this).contents().find('#ReportContent').outerHeight(true) + 50;`

Comment: good thinking.. the `div` will never (*on its own*) expand more than its contents... glad i could help..